# mmap() fail with ENOMEM on a 1TB ANONYMOUS file?

Tags: c

I'm trying to mmap an 1TB anonymous file under Fedora Linux x86_64 (4G RAM plus 16G swap). But I got ENOMEM "cannot allocate memory" and even for 32G as the following code. Am I missing anything? Appreciate any clue.

```
#define HEAP_SIZE (1UL << 35)
int main()
{
    void *addr = mmap(0, HEAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("mmap %d gbytes succeed\n", HEAP_SIZE/(1UL << 30));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default Linux overcommit policy prevents you from allocating this much memory.  You don't have anywhere near 1TB of RAM, and the kernel will give you `ENOMEM` now rather than running the OOM killer later... but you can change this policy.

```
$ /sbin/sysctl vm.overcommit_memory
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
$ sudo /sbin/sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
```

Policy 1 is "always overcommit", which is useful for certain applications.  Policy 2 is "never overcommit".  The default policy, 0, allows some overcommit but uses heuristics to reject large allocations, like the one which failed on your computer.

### Alternative

You could also use the `MAP_NORESERVE` flag.  Note that the kernel will ignore this flag if its policy is to "never overcommit".

Comment: +1 for `MAP_NORESERVE`. If this is the kind of application where you can spare the time to allow things to get paged in later, then this flag could be right for you.

Comment: `MAP_NORESERVE` is a no-op if overcommit is fully off (2).