# mmap cannot alloacte memory ENOMEM

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, redhat

I've 64 bit kernel, and 8GB RAM. 
We are running majorly 5 or 6 process.
when new process ie process 6 invoked, and just after that it is crashing and it is not even generating core file. But using strace I found below place it is failing.

```
**045232 mmap(NULL, 3716493312, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
0.000141 mmap(NULL, 3716624384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
0.000103 mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x61c5c000**
```

Please some one can give inputs why I'm getting this issue and exiting my process. what I've to do to fix this issue, your inputs are very valuable. thanks

Comment: See this previous [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16271041/1079907).

Comment: Hi, the above post fix did not solve my problem. same again it is crashing.